# Solution set of any polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, dense-subspaces

Lee in Introduction to Topological Manifolds claims that the solution set $X(f)$ of any polynomial $f\neq 0$ in two variables over $\mathbb{R}$ is nowhere dense i.e. $A:=\mathbb{R}^2-\overline{X(f)}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Here is what I have tried:

If for any non-empty open subset $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, $U\cap A=\emptyset$ then $U\cap \overline{X(f)}\neq\emptyset$. Hence, $\overline{X(f)}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. $\overline{X(f)}=\mathbb{R}^2$.

At this point I am stuck or I am not sure whether what I am doing is right: judging by the fact that Zariski topology (I am also doing some commuatative algebra) on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is coarser than the Euclidean topology, the algebraic set $X(f)$ is closed with respect to the Euclidean topology and hence $X(f)=\overline{X(f)}=\mathbb{R}^2$. I believe that this is true iff $f$ is the zero polynomial, hence I have a contradiction.

Here I don't really need the Zariski topology to give me the closedness. Instead, thanks to a friend, it would be simply enough to note that the solution set is pre-image $f^{-1}(0)$ of $0$ which is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Finally, primages of closed sets under continuous maps are closed. But I believe the proof is structurally wrong, for now.

I would greatly appreciate if any mistakes are pointed out. Also I would be thankful for alternative ways to approach this problem.

Comment: We should prove this (contrapositive):  Let $f \in \mathbb R[x,y]$.  If $U$ is a nonempty open set and $f$ vanishes on $U$, then $f$ vanishes everywhere.

Comment: The negation of "nowhere dense" is not "dense."

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu, indeed I had believed wrong. I think the negation of the statement $A$ is nowhere dense in $X$ is that $X-\overline{A}$ is NOT dense in $X$ which happens already when $A$ has a non-empty interior, i.e. an open subset of $X$ is subset of $A\subseteq \overline{A}$ and this does not have any points in common with $X-\overline{A}$.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for your suggestion. I will work on it and get back to you :))

Comment: @GEdgar Basically my argument boiled down to saying in $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$, every analytic function that is constant on an open neighbourhood is constant on the entire space, after noticing that polynomial functions are analytic. Does this makes sense? Also is there a way to extend the statement and/or my attempt at a proof to polynomials in $n$ variables over $\mathbb{R}$?